# SQLPLUS Value Trouble

Tags: select, sqlplus

I have a problem with an SQL Query.

I have been tasked to display the names of employees who have sold to at least 4 different stores.

I have written the following query:

```
select EmpCode from Items
group by EmpCode
having COUNT (EmpCode)>=4
order by EmpCode desc;
```

But I am still getting values for those employees who have sold to the same store, the result being:

```
EMPCODE
-------
   E4
   E3
   E2
   E1
```

I am made aware that others have been getting various other answers, but the most common is just 1 value being returned.

The table contains "ItemNo, StoreNo, ItemDesc, Quant, Units, ReorderNo, Price, EmpCode"
    The table has a total of 34 records with 0 null values.
    Multiple employees have sold multiple number of items to various different stores.
    But the full table shows that only E3 has sold to **4 different stores**
        whilst others have sold to either the same store, two stores or three stores.
    I wish to show that E3 is the only Employee to have sold to 4 different stores.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: provide info on your table structure will help to understand your problem

Comment: Added information on the table structure, hope this helps

Comment: Just to be sure of the semantics of this table: if they are what you say they are, why is, say, ItemDec in that table?  Will an item have a different description when it is sold by E1 at store 1 than if it is sold by E2 at the same store or by E1 at store 2?  Is there a normalisation issue or is the table really a view?

Comment: The Item description is just the name of the item itself, it is preferable to have an ItemNo + ItemDesc for readability. The task says that there is no need for normalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `COUNT(DISTINCT StoreNo)`:

```
select EmpCode 
from Items
group by EmpCode
having COUNT (DISTINCT StoreNo)>=4
order by EmpCode desc;
```